# Express SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, express

Trying to send raw data as params in express...and at fields variable im getting error...

```js
function getWithQuery(req,res){
    console.log(req.params);
    var query = {name: new RegExp(name, 'i')};
    var fields = {"_id","name"};//i tried {_id, name}; and {'_id', 'name'}
    var maxRecs = 10;
    var sort = {name};
    dataService.getWithQuery(query, fields, maxRecs, sort)
    .then(function(data){
        if (data){
            res.send(data);
        }else {
            res.sendStatus(404).send("Doc dont exists");
        }
    })
    .catch(function (err){
        console.log("doc dont exists" + err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });
}
```

this is the error...

```
var  fields = {"_id","name"};
                    ^
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Do suggest how to modify...*thanks in advance*

Comment: `{"_id" : null,"name": null}` is this you want? The syntax that you are trying to use is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from your syntax: if you want an object, you are missing a `:`:

```
var  fields = {_id: name};
```

If you want an array then you have to put `[]` instead of `{}`:

```
var  fields = ["_id", "name"];
```

And I may be wrong, but I think you will also run into a problem with your `var sort = {name}` syntax.